# How can i get running path in class library on web?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml

i have a class library which named "fAgent.dll" and i use this dll file in two application. one application is desktop app and other one is web. this dll file have to read a bin file or a xml file. i can open the bin file on desktop like this:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\MyApp\\ConnSettings.bin", FileMode.Open);
```

if dll can't found bin file, it try to read a xml file like this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
var path = (new System.Uri(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase)).AbsolutePath;
doc.Load(path + "\fCns.xml");
```

on FileNotFoundException it try this code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
System.Reflection.Assembly asm = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(fAgent.Tools));
string asmPath = asm.CodeBase;
doc.Load(asmPath.Replace("fAgent.DLL", "fCns.xml"));
```

Xml file and dll file is in the same folder. it works on desktop and it doesn't work on the web. i have to get the "~/bin" folder on the web without using Mappath function. how can i do this?

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [HttpRuntime.BinDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.bindirectory.aspx) property or even better - put file into the `App_Data` folder instead of the bin as if you will modify file in the bin folder application will restart

```
var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.BinDirectory, "ConnSettings.bin");
```

Comment: sorry, it's not worked. i use bin folder because i never change this xml file.

Comment: I've edit answer. If it's still not working check is `ConnSettings.bin` really exists in the `bin` folder

Comment: with this code i can access the file but when i publish, it's not working. may be, i have to use virtual path. because on the web, filePath returns: "c:\inetpub\wwwroot\bin\ConnSettings.bin" this path is correct but not working...